# Same figure & changing text as "arrowing" through the presentation (Beamer)

Tags: beamer

I tried to build my first presentation and met my first problem: I would like to know how to create a part of my presentation that looks like the example below. Instead of writing 3 frames, I would lite to write 1 frame which contains a figure and some text beneath it; and I would like the text to change as I 'arrow' through the presentation, because that makes it easier to explain a figure. Otherwise, I would be forced to change the "pages" all the time back and forth. What would be annoying for my audiance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
bla    1
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
bla 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
bla 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So in this example the figure stays the same, but the text (underneath) changes. Does anyone know how to get that result?

Comment: I don't really understand the phrasing of the question. I think that instead of writing 3 frames, you want to write 1 frame which contains a figure and some text beneath it; you would like the text to change as you 'arrow' through the presentation. Is this an accurate interpretation?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to say. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, I did understand correctly.

Comment: @Philip It might be useful for future readers to make the edit.

Comment: @cmhughes: I did so. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I must admit that I'm not *totally* sure that I understand what you want, but if I do then I would do (something like) the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure}

Caption
\end{center}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<+|handout:0>
bla    1
\onslide<+|handout:0>
bla 2
\onslide<+-|handout:0>
bla 3
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've changed the `figure` environment to just a plain `center`: you probably don't want your figure floating around the page.  This also meant changing the `\caption` to just the caption.

The `overprint` environment is a bit like an `itemize` environment in that its contents get divided up.  In this case, by the `\onslide` commands.  Each of those specifies some content to be put on a particular slide (the stuff between the successive `\onslide` commands).  The `overprint` environment ensures that it takes up the same amount of space on each slide, which makes it so that there's no danger of the picture "jumping" between slide transitions (as can sometimes happen if stuff takes up different amounts of vertical space on the slides).

For more on `beamer` and how to handle successive slides, I heartily recommend reading the user guide.  If there's stuff in the above that you don't understand, I can happily point you to the relevant part of the guide.  For example, the `overprint` environment is explained in section 9.5 of the manual.  If things like `\onslide` are new to you then I suggest you start with the "tutorial" section at the start of the manual to see what is possible.  (And, of course, ask questions here.)